# NetSuite Advance PDF/HTML template, sourcing the contact field from the PO transaction to the pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, netsuite

I am trying to source the contact information on a purchase order transaction but it is retrieving the information from the attention field on the address, any idea how to do so I have tried using the field ID but still, no information is showing.

below are the screenshots for your reference.
[PO transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJvg3.png)

I tried using the attention code but it shows the field from the address. I also tried using the `${record.entityid_contact_name}` code but nothing is showing.

I am expecting the contact field to only populate the name Lori B on the pdf template.

Answer (score 0):

First of all contact record is linked to entity (vendor or customer) not transaction. So you will need to create a custom transaction body field to store this value before you can print on PDF.

**1. Create Transaction Body Field to store the Vendor's primary contact Name**

- Navigate to Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Transaction Body Fields > New
- Label: Enter Contact Name
- Id: vendor_pri_contact (*You can name this base on your own convention)
- Type: Select Free Form Text
- Store Value: Uncheck Checkmark (* Important)
- Click Applies To
  Purchase: Enter Checkmark
- Click Display
  Subtab: Select Main
- Click Validation & Defaulting
  -- Default Value: Enter {vendor.contact}
  -- Formula: Enter Checkmark
- Click [Save]

**2. Make sure vendor has a primary contact set.**

> At the vendor record, Relationships tab, click [Update primary]
> Assign "Primary Contact" role to the contact that you want to print on PDF

**3. At the PDF html code, reference to the custom transaction body field id** e.g. record.vendor_pri_contact

Hope this help.